# Convert lonlat to GPS used values

Tags: php, javascript, dictionary, gps, openstreetmap

I have the following code. How to convert lonlat value to GPS used values in degrees?

UPDATE: I'm not sure that I use correct vocabulary, but currently `lonlat` is equal to something like this '2698.98978 1232.8998'. I want to conver to degrees, e.g. '41.2987 2.1989'.

`lonlat` is a variable. Please see in the code.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function init(){
      map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
      base_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
      "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
      map.addLayer(base_layer);
      map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      map.events.register('click', map, handleMapClick);
    } 

    function handleMapClick(evt)
    {
       var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(evt.xy);
       // use lonlat
       alert(lonlat);
    } 
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
  Hello Map.<br />
 <div id="map"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/

Comment: I'm not sure that I use correct vocabulary, but currently lonlat is equal to something like this '2698.98978 1232.8998'. I want to conver to degrees, e.g. '41.2987 2.1989'.

Comment: I am not familiar with Open Layers, but I read in the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html) that a LonLat.lon is "The x-axis coordinate in map units.  If your map is in a geographic projection, this will be the Longitude.  Otherwise, it will be the x coordinate of the map location in your map units." So what you are looking for is a way to convert your map units to degrees, or to make your map "in a geographic projection."

Comment: @David Gorsline: I know this. But when I tried ll.transform(map.projection,map.displayProjection); alert(ll.lon);, the output is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the  `getLonLatFromViewPortPx` but the `getLonLatFromPixel` method like this:

```
var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(evt.xy);
```

This will give you the correct coordinates without any transforms.